# AWS Lightsail Plesk make DB externally accessible

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, plesk, amazon-lightsail

I'm using Plesk installed at AWS Lighsail, I'm using the defauls MySQL database for my application. And now I'm trying to make this database externally accessible.

I've followed [these](https://www.plesk.com/kb/support/how-to-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-server-in-plesk/) instructions to whitelist the IP addresses

But the problem is not whitelisting, but more like making it accessible at all.

It shows `localhost` as the DB domain and I can't find how to change this or how to create an alias/forwarding or something.

[image]

The only mentions for that case I was able to find [here](https://www.plesk.com/kb/docs/accessing-databases-with-connection-strings/) which says:

> If the server name is specified like ‘localhost’, contact your hosting provider to find out your database server address.

What can I do? Contact AWS? (my billing plan does not support this lol) Create external DB from scratch in Lightsail and point Plesk to use it instead?

Thank you!

Comment: It's `localhost` on the LightSail server, so the public address is the same as the LightSail server's address.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I’m also  stuck here I point to the public up and can’t connect.